# inconsistencies with display in IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

The site http://www.mytravel.bm uses a jQuery slider  for images and text on the front page..

In Chrome/Firefox/Safari they seem to render just fine, but in IE8, the image only appears for the first slide, and the black box and text seem to disappear for the others as well

I've taken a look at the inspector, but am not sure as to how it's happening...

any help?

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Page works just fine for me in IE8/

Comment: That screenshot is in IE8 in XP .. could it be a CUFON issue?

Comment: might be cache related. Clear your cache and reload your browser to check again. It looks the same for me in IE8/FF/Chrome.

Comment: Nice Joomla website (you should do something about that favico.ico in your root)

Comment: yeah thanks, you don't have anything to say about the display issues do you?

Answer (score 0):

You have this error:

```
jQuery("img").lazyload is not a function
effect : "fadeIn"
```

And for me it works fine in IE 8

Comment: You think that would cause issues with the display?